# Node.js hosting multiple separate DBs in one application

Tags: mysql, node.js

I would like to roll an application that can serve multiple "companies". I don't want to share, for data protection reasons, the same DB for multiple companies, but I would like to use a connection pooling across the same database.

Is the context switching of using "USE DATABASES..." acceptable each time there's a request, or there should be a completely different way to design such kinds of applications?

I mean, going this way, will make also the application easily scalable and/or containerised. I cannot figure another way otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/06/how-design-multiclient-databases/) help?

Comment: not really. This takes two opposite sides approaches, while if you want to maximize resources and scale consistently, I think you should target the same host with different databases.